# Is there any kind of a 'default' AMI ID across all EC2 regions?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

The `ec2-run-instances` command needs an AMI ID and the ID is different across all regions. Is there any way to specify that I need an AMI that will be suitable for region x / zone y and instance_type z?

In other words I need a way to use some "default" AMI so that I can write a script that will work across all EC2 regions.

Comment: This is a common question, and one I had as well. I wrote a tool to automate creating a map given a starting region and AMI ID. It's ami_lookup, on [Github](https://github.com/CodeSolid/ami-lookup) and in [this article](http://codesolid.com/How-to-Easily-Create-Region-Maps-for-AMIs-in-CloudFormation-Templates/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing like a default AMI for [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), and no concept of selecting a default (or rather the region specific) AMI amongst the otherwise identical AMIs with different IDs per region either (a region independent AMI ID would be a nifty improvement though).

This is usually solved by adding a respective mapping to your script, thus depends on the scripting environment in use (a simple map should always be available somehow) - e.g. [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) uses the very same approach itself, see the sample [EC2ChooseAMI.template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/EC2ChooseAMI.template), which is an *example of using Mappings to select an AMI based on region and instance type*.

The *AWSRegionArch2AMI* map achieves what you desire, plus offering a choice of architecture as well (which implies a hint why a default AMI ID could not be as easy to implement then it might look at fist sight).